# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse

### outOfBoundsException

Hola. Estoy teniendo problemas con este fragmento de código:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.ImageStack;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;
public class StatisticalSignificance { 
static int[][] rRed, rGreen, rBlue; 
public int w, h; 
public StatisticalSignificance(ColocalizationCoefficients cc, boolean r, 
boolean R, boolean i,
        boolean k, boolean m, int seed, int gImages, String level, String 
 channel3)
{
w=150;
h=150;
rRed = stack2D();
}
public int[][] stack2D()
{
int[][] vec = new int[w][w*h];
for(int z=0; z<w; z++)
    {   
    for(int x=0; x<w*h; x++)
        {
        vec[z][x]=(int)(Math.random()*250);
        }
    }
return vec;
}
static int toto() { return rRed[0][0]; }
 }
```

recibo siempre esta excepcion cuando ejecuto el método toto desde otra clase:

```
 Exception in thread "Run$_main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
   at ar.com.yahoojuliobuonfigli.imagej.StatisticalSignificance.toto(StatisticalSignificance.java:515)
at ar.com.yahoojuliobuonfigli.imagej.MRF_main.run(MRF_main.java:276)
at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:217)
at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:181)
at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:170)
at ar.com.yahoojuliobuonfigli.imagej.MRF_main.main(MRF_main.java:299)
```

Y para cualquier indices de rRed recibo el mismo error. No se como solucionarlo. No veo ningún error lógico. Ya cambié de compilador del 1.6 al 1.8 y nada.
 Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Agrega el código donde llamas al método `toto()`

Comment: Yo veo que quieres asignar un arreglo con tamaño a uno que no tiene tamaño y que aparte es estatico

Comment: Hola. Gracias por las respuestas, no quería poner tanto código. Son dos clases largas. Voy a resumirlas

Comment: Gracias abrahams y Betanzos, lo solucioné agregando esta sentencia: rRed = new int[w][w*h]; que pensé no era necesaria. Pensé que dentro del método se instanciaba la variable, de hecho creo haberlo hecho otras veces y el programa corría sin errores de ejecución. Saludos